# Numpy ndarray hstack by reference

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference, overloading

When I try to define the `+=` in an object Class I want to modify a `numpy.ndarray` by reference.

I have the following two objects which are `numpy.ndarray`, `a1` and `a2`:

```
>>> a1
array([array([ 0.04168576,  0.13111852,  0.91896599]),
       array([ 0.81658056,  0.50832376,  1.59519731]),
       array([ 0.20646088,  0.13335052,  1.19661452])], dtype=object)
>>> a2
array([array([ 0.25765112,  0.54137219,  0.26067181]),
       array([ 0.57738128,  0.45649817,  1.6323892 ]),
       array([ 0.2328858 ,  0.4922151 ,  1.00012122])], dtype=object)
```

In my class I want to implement a `self.__iand__` and want some way to write:

```
a1.append(a2)
```

to give the equivalent of the following:

```
>>> np.hstack((a1,a2))
array([array([ 0.04168576,  0.13111852,  0.91896599]),
       array([ 0.81658056,  0.50832376,  1.59519731]),
       array([ 0.20646088,  0.13335052,  1.19661452]),
       array([ 0.25765112,  0.54137219,  0.26067181]),
       array([ 0.57738128,  0.45649817,  1.6323892 ]),
       array([ 0.2328858 ,  0.4922151 ,  1.00012122])], dtype=object)
```

and to have `a1` **change by reference**.

I want to avoid writing

```
a1 = np.hstack((a1,a2))
```

because the actual arrays are very large and this is for a Monte Carlo application and I have got to try to keep performance very fast whenever I can.

Currently when I try to implement this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

**Other related Questions:**

[The following Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585793/are-numpy-arrays-passed-by-reference) is useful for explaining how functions can pass by reference, but doesn't address by problem.

[Whereas the answer provided by @SvenMarnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array) mentions this exact issue, but no solution is provided.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using a numpy array here rather than a plain Python `list`? Object arrays are essentially glorified lists - by using the `np.object` dtype you are already giving up most of the performance benefits of using numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes @ali_m. I have been using numpy arrays because they give a significant performance increase when I am generating my long lists of random numbers (crucial for the Monto Carlo simulation). Additionally there are many row and column operations that I want to do, many of which have better performance when using `np.array` rather than `list`. Originally I used lists of lists, but this gave a worse performance by a factor of 20 when I timed my operations.

Comment: That may be true for the inner arrays which contain float scalars, but I *highly* doubt you would see much performance difference if you switched the outer container from an `np.object` array to a `list`. See  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768305/1461210), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768083/1461210) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28284961/1461210).